# Extracting kubernetes service address (of nodePort type) using python client for kubernetes

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, devops

I have the following service running on my *2-node local kubernetes cluster*. The service was originally deployed on *aws ec2 cluster* and used **LoadBalancer** type. I changed it to nodePort type in my local setting.

**Problem:** At some point of the application in the cloud deployment, a **python client to kubernetes** extracts the service address by the following method.

```
def get_service_address(client, svc_name):
 
    try:
        service = client.read_namespaced_service(namespace=NAMESPACE,
                                                 name=svc_name)

    except k8s.client.rest.ApiException:
        return None


    while service.status.load_balancer.ingress is None:  or \
            service.status.load_balancer.ingress[0].hostname is None:
   
        service = client.read_namespaced_service(namespace=NAMESPACE,
                                                 name=svc_name)
       

    return service.status.load_balancer.ingress[0].hostname
```

But as I am using nodePort in local setting, the execution gets stuck in the while loop since the `service.status.load_balancer.ingress` or the `service.status.load_balancer.ingress[0].hostname` variable always returning `None`. My question is how can I get the service address in my local setting if I am using nodePort type? What changes I can make in the method mentioned above?

### Kubectl returns the following about the service after I changed it to nodePort type from LoadBalancer.

**$ kubectl get services**

```
NAME              TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                                                       AGE
kubernetes        ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP                                                       12d
routing-service   NodePort    10.110.112.90   <none>        6450:31854/TCP,6451:30163/TCP,6452:30037/TCP,6453:31511/TCP   31h
```

**$ kubectl describe svc routing-service**

```
Name:                     routing-service
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   <none>
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 role=routing
Type:                     NodePort
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.110.112.90
IPs:                      10.110.112.90
Port:                     routing-0  6450/TCP
TargetPort:               6450/TCP
NodePort:                 routing-0  31854/TCP
Endpoints:                141.215.12.58:6450,141.215.80.72:6450
Port:                     routing-1  6451/TCP
TargetPort:               6451/TCP
NodePort:                 routing-1  30163/TCP
Endpoints:                141.215.12.58:6451,141.215.80.72:6451
Port:                     routing-2  6452/TCP
TargetPort:               6452/TCP
NodePort:                 routing-2  30037/TCP
Endpoints:                141.215.12.58:6452,141.215.80.72:6452
Port:                     routing-3  6453/TCP
TargetPort:               6453/TCP
NodePort:                 routing-3  31511/TCP
Endpoints:                141.215.12.58:6453,141.215.80.72:6453
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

**$ kubectl get service routing-service  -o yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2021-07-24T15:45:18Z"
  name: routing-service
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "1245567"
  uid: d8d9155c-cfdd-4203-ad8c-03c80d514e91
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.110.112.90
  clusterIPs:
  - 10.110.112.90
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - name: routing-0
    nodePort: 31854
    port: 6450
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 6450
  - name: routing-1
    nodePort: 30163
    port: 6451
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 6451
  - name: routing-2
    nodePort: 30037
    port: 6452
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 6452
  - name: routing-3
    nodePort: 31511
    port: 6453
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 6453
  selector:
    role: routing
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: NodePort
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Comment: You should be able to use dns instead of the k8s API to get the service address if you know the service name and namespace. Just a simple `dig <service_name>.<namespace_name>` from a container inside of the cluster. See: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/

Comment: Thanks @jordanm but I must have to get the address inside the `def get_service_address(client, svc_name):` method mentioned. Therefore, I have to rely on k8s API.

Comment: I'm suggesting you change the `get_service_adress()` method to just do a DNS lookup.